# send data packet to all clients using HTTP binding in WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

I created a wcf service. and i want to broadcast data packets to all my clients using this service at every interval of time. I have used the callback , but it is a different concept. Please let me know how can i do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by clients? In a webservice you don't have clients connected waiting to be contacted.

Answer (score 0):

A callback contract will allow you to send a push to your web service clients. I am not sure what you mean by "a different concept".

In my experience, although it works, callback contracts in WCF are complicated at best. I would move to a binding which supports asynchronous queuing (like netMsmqBinding).

This would allow you to store information on your service about your service clients and push data to them as necessary.